# chunking huge query with withcount and orderby

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

i have a pretty heavy query that hits the memory limit and return 500 error here is the query :

```
       $collection = User::with('city')
            ->withCount('userReferral')
            ->orderByDesc('user_referral_count')
            ->get();

        $data  = $collection->where('username', $userName);
```

this is for a ranking that shows the user rank on the ranking of the users based on the count of user she/he invited to site . this now returns 500 on server which is because of memory limit which i dont want it to consume that amount of memory . how can i rewrite this with chunk so it consume less memory ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not use the where of the collection but run it using eloquent directly.

```
$collection = User::with('city')
        ->withCount('userReferral')
        ->orderByDesc('user_referral_count')
        ->where('username', $userName)
        ->get();

// Do something with your collection
```

If you don't need all users at once you can also use [pagination](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/pagination).

```
$collection = User::with('city')
        ->withCount('userReferral')
        ->orderByDesc('user_referral_count')
        ->where('username', $userName)
        ->paginate(10);
```

Comment: or use `->take(10)` if a  short sample is needed

Answer (score 1):

A good option is to always use `limit`, and use pagination or lazy-loading or other means of showing your results by chunks, and not pull them all at once.

Another way you can optimize the query is to `select` ONLY the fields you actually need, instead of all of them.

Comment: ...and not get all results just to filter them out later (like running "where" on the result instead of in the original query)